# GCP app deploy in preview URL

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I started using Google Cloud Platform and been testing some things on it. After deploying the web services (`node.js`), the GCP provides a URL which actually redirects to a preview URL. Ex- `project.appspot.com` to `project.appspot-preview.com`. Due to this, our client side throws `307` status code but not if I use the preview URL directly.
All I want to know is, is it safe to use the preview URL straight away or is there anyway to disable the forwarding?

Need help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current behavior of the latest GAE flex environment. From [Domain update](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#domain_update):

> Traffic is now served from the `appspot-preview.com` domain instead of
>   the `appspot.com` domain. All traffic from the App Engine flexible
>   environment will be automatically redirected to the new domain. All
>   App Engine Standard traffic will continue to be through `appspot.com`.
>   When the App Engine flexible environment is generally available (GA),
>   users will be able to use the `appspot.com` or `appspot-preview.com`
>   domains for routing traffic.
>
> For users who want to use the latest App Engine Flexible release with
>   a custom domain, please fill out [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/gae_flex_custom_domain) to contact us.